# CustomTableProvider in Version 7 vs. 8.2

Tags: c#, kentico

I'm new to Kentico and inherited some code.

In version 7 of Kentico a `CustomTableProvider` is being created like this:

`new CustomTableItemProvider(CMSContext.CurrentUser)`

According to the [documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/api-changes/kentico-8/5276), Kentico recommends the above call should be replaced with this call:

`new CustomTableItemProvider(System.String)`

There are two problems I see. First, the recommended constructor is marked as **Obsolete**. Second, even if I **do** decide to use the new constructor, it's not clear to me how a parameter that used to be of type `CMSContext.CurrentUser` should map to a `String`. The documentation says nothing.

What's the right way to get a `CustomTableProvider` that is semantically equivalent to the one created using the version 7 API?

Comment: Can you provide some code or explain what your code trying to do with the object? Is it trying to insert a new or update an existing item in the CustomTable?

Answer (score 1):

In v8.2 API the constructor no longer accepts CMSContext.CurrentUser instead it requires a System.String that represents the CustomTable class name.

So this would instantiate an object of CustomTableItemProvider:

```
string customTableClassName = "customtable.sampletable";
CustomTableItemProvider ctip = new CustomTableItemProvider(customTableClassName);
```

However as you mentioned in 8.2 it is marked as Obsolete, in v8.2 there are new API methods to work with CustomTables, if you could provide a sample of your code or an explanation of what you are trying to achieve I could provide a more specific answer and example.

You could also have a look in the Source Code of your Kentico Solution. They have included some generic examples of working with CustomTables via API. The path in your Solution is:

**\CMSAPIExamples\Code\Development\CustomTables\Default.aspx.cs**